# How to reuse Word wrap algorithm in textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, algorithm, word-wrap

I know TextBox/TextBlock already support text word wrap very well. (Windows WPF)

the question is how can I reuse that logic? so I don't need to write an other word wrap util class for this purpose.

Any feedback would be great appericated!

Comment: Where are you wanting to reuse it? In UI code, or in back-end code of some sort? If UI, TextBlock already supports word-wrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithms to do this have been around for ages and are relatively simple.  You'd be a lot better off using one of the standard algorithms rather than trying to duct-tape something to a textbox.  Try the wikipedia page for starters: [Word Wrap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_wrap)